# Create new column based on replicate observation

Tags: r, append, data-manipulation, replicate

I have a question how to create a new column based on another.
Here is my part of `data`:

```
Category  Brand    Time1          value   Time2        number   
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1      
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1
```

I show 4 obs. of `data` above, and I explain my `data` more:
First, see the structure.

```
> str(data)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  105907 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Category     : num  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
$ Brand        : chr  "HTC" "APPLE" "INFOCUS" "APPLE" ...
$ Time1        : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
$ value        : num  1724 2946 330 2946 2946 ...
$ Time2        : POSIXct, format: NA NA NA "2015-01-03" ...
$ number         : chr  "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Second, I want to **replicate** each obs. based on `Time1`.
   This is my code:

```
data[,rep:=ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)][]
```

Now, the `data` looks like:

```
Category  Brand    Time1          value   Time2        number   rep
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13       
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13       
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13   
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13     
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3
```

Third, I want to create a new column `Lapse`, and the result I want is:

```
Category  Brand    Time1          value   Time2        number   rep   Lapse
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    0   
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    1   
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    2
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    3 
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    4
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    5
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    6
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    7 
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    8
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    9 
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    10 
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    11
2         HTC      2015-01-01     1724    NA           1        13    12
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    0
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    1
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    2
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    3
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    4
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    5
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    6
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    7
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    8
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    9 
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    10
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    11
6         APPLE    2015-10-10     3000    2015-10-30   1        13    12 
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    0
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    1
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    2
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    3
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    4
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    5 
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    6 
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    7
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    8
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    9
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    10 
2         APPLE    2016-01-15     430     NA           1        12    11
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3     0
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3     1
NA        Samsung  2016-10-20     860     2016-12-20   1        3     2
```

Above is the result I want, I try the code like this:

```
data[,Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1, by = (Category,Brand,Time1,value,Time2,number)]
```

However, it is wrong.

If it is right,

```
uniqie(data$Lapse) 
[1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
```

But, I got `0~999`. I think my code is wrong.
Any suggestion?
Or maybe there are other good ways to do like this?

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
data <- "    Category        Brand Time1 value Time2 number
1:        2          HTC    2015-01-01    1724       NA    1
2:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2946       NA    1
3:        2      INFOCUS    2015-01-01     330       NA    1
4:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2946 2015-01-03    1
5:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2946       NA    1
6:        2      Samsung    2015-01-01    2189       NA    1
7:        2          HTC    2015-01-01     730       NA    1
8:        2      Samsung    2015-01-01    2189       NA    1
9:        2      Samsung    2015-01-01    2189       NA    1
10:        2          HTC    2015-01-01    1296       NA    1
11:        2          HTC    2015-01-01     730       NA    1
12:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2189       NA    1
13:        2      INFOCUS    2015-01-01     330 2015-01-02    1
14:        2          HTC    2015-01-01    2189       NA    1
15:        2         SONY    2015-01-01    1296       NA    1
16:        2          HTC    2015-01-01     730       NA    1
17:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2946       NA    1
18:        2        APPLE    2015-01-01    2946       NA    1
19:        2          HTC    2015-01-01    1724       NA    1
20:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02    1724       NA    1
21:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02    2189       NA    1
22:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
23:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02    2189       NA    1
24:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
25:        2        APPLE    2015-01-02    2946       NA    1
26:        2          HTC    2015-01-02    1724       NA    1
27:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
28:        2         ASUS    2015-01-02     330       NA    1
29:        2         ASUS    2015-01-02     330       NA    1
30:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02    1724       NA    1
31:        2        APPLE    2015-01-02    2189       NA    1
32:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
33:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
34:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
35:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
36:        2          HTC    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
37:        2      Samsung    2015-01-02     730       NA    1
38:        2        APPLE    2015-01-03    2189       NA    1
39:        2        APPLE    2015-01-03    2946       NA    1
40:        2       Benten    2015-01-03     330       NA    1
41:        2        APPLE    2015-01-03    2946       NA    1
42:        2      INFOCUS    2015-01-03     330       NA    1
43:        2      Samsung    2015-01-03    1296       NA    1
44:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
45:        2      Samsung    2015-01-03    2189       NA    1
46:        2         SONY    2015-01-03    2189       NA    1
47:        2 TaiwanMobile    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
48:        2          HTC    2015-01-03    1296       NA    1
49:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
50:        2        APPLE    2015-01-03    2189       NA    1
51:        2        APPLE    2015-01-03    2189       NA    1
52:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
53:        2      Samsung    2015-01-03     330       NA    1
54:        2 TaiwanMobile    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
55:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
56:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
57:        2 TaiwanMobile    2015-01-03     330       NA    1
58:        2      Samsung    2015-01-03    1724 2015-01-04    1
59:        2          HTC    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
60:        2      INFOCUS    2015-01-03     330       NA    1
61:        2         SONY    2015-01-03     730       NA    1
62:        2          HTC    2015-01-04     730       NA    1
63:        2          HTC    2015-01-04     730       NA    1
64:        2        APPLE    2015-01-04    2189 2015-01-05    1
65:        2 TaiwanMobile    2015-01-04     730 2015-01-05    1"  

data <- read.table(text=data, header = TRUE)
data <- as.data.table(data)
data <- data[,rep:=ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)][]
data[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1 , .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]

dput(droplevels(head(data,65)))
structure(list(Category = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Brand = c("HTC", "APPLE", 
"INFOCUS", "APPLE", "APPLE", "Samsung", "HTC", "Samsung", "Samsung", 
"HTC", "HTC", "APPLE", "INFOCUS", "HTC", "SONY", "HTC", "APPLE", 
"APPLE", "HTC", "Samsung", "Samsung", "HTC", "Samsung", "HTC", 
"APPLE", "HTC", "HTC", "ASUS", "ASUS", "Samsung", "APPLE", "HTC", 
"Samsung", "HTC", "HTC", "HTC", "Samsung", "APPLE", "APPLE", 
"Benten", "APPLE", "INFOCUS", "Samsung", "HTC", "Samsung", "SONY", 
"TaiwanMobile", "HTC", "HTC", "APPLE", "APPLE", "HTC", "Samsung", 
"TaiwanMobile", "HTC", "HTC", "TaiwanMobile", "Samsung", "HTC", 
"INFOCUS", "SONY", "HTC", "HTC", "APPLE", "TaiwanMobile"), Time1 = structure(c(1420070400, 
1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 
1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 
1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 1420070400, 
1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 
1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 
1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 1420156800, 
1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 
1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 
1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 
1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 1420243200, 
1420329600, 1420329600, 1420329600, 1420329600), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), value = c(1724, 2946, 330, 2946, 
2946, 2189, 730, 2189, 2189, 1296, 730, 2189, 330, 2189, 1296, 
730, 2946, 2946, 1724, 1724, 2189, 730, 2189, 730, 2946, 1724, 
730, 330, 330, 1724, 2189, 730, 730, 730, 730, 730, 730, 2189, 
2946, 330, 2946, 330, 1296, 730, 2189, 2189, 730, 1296, 730, 
2189, 2189, 730, 330, 730, 730, 730, 330, 1724, 730, 330, 730, 
730, 730, 2189, 730), Time2 = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, 1420243200, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1420156800, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1420329600, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1420416000, 
1420416000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
number = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1")), .Names = c("Category", 
"Brand", "Time1", "value", "Time2", "number"), row.names = c(NA, 
-65L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x003e24a0>, class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

And the problem is the result is weird.

```
unique(data$Lapse)
[1]  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
[38] 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73
[75] 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
```

Comment: Can you check if those NAs are real NAs or string or factors?  Also suppose if your 'Time2' after the replication is say `c(NA, NA, '2015-10-30', '2015-10-30', NA, NA)` how would the groups looks like

Comment: How can I check whether those NAs are real or not? I use `is.na(data$Time2)` and I get `[1] True True ....`, so they are real right?

Comment: Okay, then it is not character. Regarding the groups, do you think you would need `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)`

Comment: I tried to replicate your condition, but I was not able to `data1 <- data.table(Category = 2, Brand = "Apple", Time1 = as.POSIXct("2015-01-01"), value = 2946, Time2 = as.POSIXct(rep(c("2015-01-03", NA), each = 10)), number=1);  data1[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1, .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)];data1$Lapse#
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Comment: `c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)`? you mean maybe I can change `NA` to **a character NA**

Comment: No, I was checking why you got a different result.  As I showed with an example above, it is working fine for me

Comment: Maybe the problem is `Time2`? As the attached image, I think it considers `2015-01-03` and `NA` to be the same. Same as my other observations. So the groups when I use `seq_len()` will create like this

Comment: But, it is not considering same in my example 'data1'  Could you post the dput of the 'data' uptill 65 rows before we do the `Lapse` step?  I have to go now..  Will check later

Comment: @akrun I update my question, check please.

Comment: If i use the `dput` output and run the code to assign `Lapse` I get `data$Lapse#
 [1] 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 0 0 2 2 3 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 2 0 1 1 0 3 0 4 5 6 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 1 3 4 0 0 5 1 0 0 1 0 0`  Here, the 'Brand' is not ordered and if I do the `order` i.e. `data[order(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]$Lapse
 #[1] 0 0 0 1 2 3 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0`

Comment: why you know `Brand` is not ordered? So, you mean the problem is caused by `Brand`?

Comment: If you check the dput 'data', I get  `head(data$Brand, 10)#
 [1] "HTC"     "APPLE"   "INFOCUS" "APPLE"   "APPLE"   "Samsung" "HTC"     "Samsung" "Samsung" "HTC"`

Comment: Yes, but why **not ordered**? They are just `data`?

Comment: What I meant is that the `:=` will assign it to based on the original position of the values in the dataset.  It is also correct, but if you wanted to have something like `0 1 2 3 0 1 2` , the grouping variables should be ordered earlier

Comment: I don't understand why group earlier or later will affect the result.

Comment: Imagine if you have a column with `v1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "C")` then your output would be  `ave(seq_along(v1), v1, FUN = seq_along)-1#
[1] 0 0 1 1 0` and suppose if it is `v2 <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C"); ave(seq_along(v2), v2, FUN = seq_along)-1#
[1] 0 1 0 1 0`

Comment: Also, your original example was already showed to be grouped, so it give the output as expected

Comment: Do I need to use `dplyr::group_by(data, Category, Brand, Time1)` before replicating?

Comment: What we have done is correct.  Only thing is that you can either do an ordering after or before the creation of 'Lapse' column

Comment: can u edit ur answer below? I'm not sure I really understand

Comment: I try `data <- data[,rep:=ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)][]; dplyr::group_by(data,Category,Brand,Time1,value,Time2,number); data[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1 , .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]`. Still wrong

Comment: The `dplyr::group_by` is not doing anything here.  You may need `data <- data[order(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]; data[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1 , .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]`

Comment: Still not work. you can try my update code and add this into it

Comment: I am a bit lost at your update there.  I thought the rows you generated with `data <- read.table(text=data, header = TRUE)` is already replicated?

Comment: lost? copy it directly into R console and run. So you can see the datatable

Comment: Yes, that I am able to run.  What I am referring to is the original data based on the first code block dataset

Comment: I try `data <- data[order(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]`. But, if I have many columns, how can I edit my code that I don't need to type each column names

Comment: you can do `data[data[,do.call(order, .SD), .SDcols = 1:6]]`

Comment: I think you cannot get the correct value may because your example data above does not show all your columns. Thus, when you do `seq_len()`, there are many repeated value in one of your columns. @akrun's comment is awesome.

Comment: To figure out this, I think you must to order **all** your columns before create `Lapse`, and then try `data[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1 , .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]`. But `.(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)` has to change to your columns and you need to check your columns before doing this.

Comment: @akrun I run Chen's update code and I can get his example and get the same result with him. I think if you do, you will get the same. The problem may be caused by his other columns, not showing in this question.

Comment: @akrun I think you can add your comment to your answer in the following

Comment: @PeterTW  Thanks, I am waiting for the OP to give some more info

Comment: @akrun what is OP? sorry, I didn't use this platform for a long time

Comment: @PeterTW  I meant the original poster

Comment: @PeterTW thanks, it is actually caused by other columns that I didn't post in the question.

Comment: @akrun I solved this. Your code is right. However, the problem is due to other columns. I shouldn't `subset` my data but should order them after reading into Rstudio immediately.

Comment: However, I don't really understand why my data in the above update question cannot create correctly. Even I order them before create `Lapse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the original data is not updated as it has the same number of rows as before.   If we check the output of

```
data[,rep:=ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)]
```

and then the

```
data
```

it becomes obvious.

So, we assign the output from the two steps back to the original object ('data') or another object (if we don't want to change the original object)

```
data <-  data[,rep:=ifelse(year(Time1)==2016, 12-month(Time1)+1, 13)][rep(1:.N,rep)]
```

and create the 'Lapse' column based on the sequence by group

```
data[, Lapse := seq_len(.N)-1 , .(Category, Brand, Time1, value, Time2, number)]
data
    Category   Brand      Time1 value      Time2 number rep Lapse
 1:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     0
 2:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     1
 3:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     2
 4:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     3
 5:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     4
 6:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     5
 7:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     6
 8:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     7
 9:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     8
10:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13     9
11:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13    10
12:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13    11
13:        2     HTC 2015-01-01  1724       <NA>      1  13    12
14:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     0
15:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     1
16:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     2
17:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     3
18:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     4
19:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     5
20:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     6
21:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     7
22:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     8
23:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13     9
24:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13    10
25:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13    11
26:        6   APPLE 2015-10-10  3000 2015-10-30      1  13    12
27:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     0
28:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     1
29:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     2
30:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     3
31:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     4
32:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     5
33:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     6
34:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     7
35:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     8
36:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12     9
37:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12    10
38:        2   APPLE 2016-01-15   430       <NA>      1  12    11
39:       NA Samsung 2016-10-20   860 2016-12-20      1   3     0
40:       NA Samsung 2016-10-20   860 2016-12-20      1   3     1
41:       NA Samsung 2016-10-20   860 2016-12-20      1   3     2
```

Comment: @PeterChen  Based on the expected you showed, I am getting the values on the example

Comment: OK, maybe the problem is my `data` I think

Comment: @PeterChen  Is it based on the original dataset or the one you showed in the example?

Comment: original dataset. So, maybe I need to check my data at first

Comment: @PeterChen  Okay, please check the str of the original data.  If possible, provide a small reproducible example that shows the problem using `dput`